# ElementStyle DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I am having an issue with the code below. What I'm trying to do with the data trigger is display a blank if the ivalueconverter(LengthConverter) decides that the 1st parameter "Binding Path=Length" is less than ConverterParameter of 3 in this case.

So for rows where that's true I get blank text. Otherwise I get my data.

The problem is as follows, if in the 1st line below Binding="{Binding Data1}" is omitted, the datatrigger works fine, however I can't edit the cell value and have it trigger the setter of Data1 to update the data. If I have things as below, I am able to edit the data, however the trigger no longer works...

Is there any way I can get both data entry and the data trigger to work?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData1" Binding="{Binding Data1}">
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Data1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Length, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with custom `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyData1">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Data1}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data1, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Your Converter should now point to Data1.Length:

```
LengthConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((value as string)?.Length??0) > 3;
    }
}
```

The Length property itself won't get a PropertyChanged event on changing the text. Therefore Bind to string Data1 directly...